# get count of the word in all files

Tags: linux, bash, grep, wc

I have a directory tree with a bunch of folders and subfolders in it and a bunch of files in those sub folders. I need to get the count of the word 'Hello' in each of those files and display the result as 'File 'a' has 'Hello' n times', 'File 'b' has 'Hello' m times' and so on. How do i write a script in linux, so that i can get the word count for the word hello in each of these files. I have tried some grep combinations with 'wc' after browsing through net , but that gave me the total count from all the files in all the folders.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

`find . -type f | xargs -n1 grep "Hello" -c`

Adding `-type f` to `find` ensures that it only returns files, not directories. Adding `-n1` to `xargs` makes it so that every file returned by `find` gets its own invocation of `grep`, so that you can get a per-file count. The `-c` argument to `grep` returns the count of matches instead of every match.

The above expression will count the number of lines that have 'Hello' in them. If you need the total number of Hellos, instead of just the number of lines that have Hello in them, you'll need to do something more sophisticated. You can use the `-o` option on grep to just print the matching section of a line, and then combine that with `wc -l` to get the number of total occurrences.

Comment: That looks good for finding the number of *lines* containing "Hello", but I'm still worried about the case where the string occurs more than once on a line.  grep will only count one in this case.  @user1455116, is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` the syntax is:

```
grep -Rc "Hello" your_dir/
```

I also recommend [`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com/) as an excellent replacement for `grep`:

```
ack -lc "Hello" your_dir/
```